# I can't change function parameter because of final declaration but i need it. How can I?

Tags: android

Here is my code:

```
public void haritaDegerAtama(final Button b, final int deger, final int deger_b){

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(deger_b==0){
                b.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.acik_mavi));
                deger_b=deger;
            }else{
                b.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.acik_gri_ton1));
                deger_b=0;
            }

        }
    });

}
```

There are 120 buttons in my project. Because of that I want to prepare a function instead of to write `onClickListener` for all each button. But I am facing a problem in my code. The error is `deger_b` variable can't change because it's 
a `final` variable. But I need to change `değer_b` variable.

How can I do that?

Comment: if i remove the final keyword, a differend error come up in this part of code "if(değer_b==0)".   It say the değer_b variable needs to be final. So if i write final an error come up, if i remove final another error come up.

Answer (score 0):

The `final` keyword is used in several contexts to define an entity that can only be assigned once. In your codes:

```
deger_b=deger;

deger_b=0;
```

will cause compiler errors. Remove `final` keyword before deger_b parameter.

Comment: if i remove the final keyword, a differend error come up in this part of code "if(değer_b==0)". It say the değer_b variable needs to be final. So if i write final an error come up, if i remove final another error come up. You can check the code in Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

i think you put final keyword for accessing the variable in inner scope but the final keyword prevents to reassign the variable so you ca change it to a property in your class and then use it in your function.
for example :

```
    class YourClass{
            private int deger_b = 0;
            .
            . 
            .
            public void haritaDegerAtama(final Button b, final int deger){

                    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            if(deger_b==0){
                                b.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.acik_mavi));
                                deger_b=deger;
                            }else{
                                b.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.acik_gri_ton1));
                                deger_b=0;
                            }

                        }
                    });

                }
                  .
                  .
                  .
             }
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But your solution is not option for me. Because:
İ will use the function is this:
haritaDegerAtama(button1,1,button1_value)
haritaDegerAtama(button2,2,button2_value)
.
:
:
haritaDegerAtama(button120,120,button120_value)


I want to change button1_value variable while changing the değer_b in the function.